# Building Hadoop on Windows 7

Tags: hadoop, io, windows-7-x64

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os) for building Apache Hadoop in Windows 7 environment.
To cut the long story short. I can compile Hadoop with `mvn compile` command and can build  packages with `mvn -package -DskipTests`

However I am unable to `mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar`
I get I/O exceptions and unable to resolve those exceptions.  I don't get these exception when building Hadoop without `-Dtar` parameter

Can someone help me in resolving these exceptions?

```
[INFO] Executing tasks
main:
      [get] Destination already exists (skipping): C:\hadoop\hadoop-hdfs-    project\hadoop-hdfs-httpfs\downloads\tomcat.tar.gz
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\hadoop\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs-httpfs\target\tomcat.exp
 [exec] tar (child): C\:hadoophadoop-hdfs-projecthadoop-hdfs-httpfs/downloads/tomcat.tar.gz: Cannot open: I/O error
 [exec] tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
 [exec]
 [exec] gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
 [exec] tar: Child returned status 2
 [exec] tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................ SUCCESS [  1.018 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM ......................... SUCCESS [  1.653 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations ......................... SUCCESS [  2.181 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies .......................... SUCCESS [  0.200 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM .................... SUCCESS [  2.889 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................ SUCCESS [  1.957 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ....................... SUCCESS [  1.570 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common .............................. SUCCESS [ 50.085 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ...................... SUCCESS [  0.090 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................ SUCCESS [ 35.510 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS .............................. FAILURE [  5.155 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-api ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-common ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-common ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-tests .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-client ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-core ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-site .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-project ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-common .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-app ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Examples .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Streaming ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distributed Copy .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Archives ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Rumen ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Gridmix ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Data Join ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Extras .............................. SKIPPED    
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Pipes ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools Dist .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distribution ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Mini-Cluster ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:43 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-19T11:24:25+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 49M/179M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "native-win" could not be activated because it does not 
exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run      dist) on project hadoop-hdfs-httpfs: An Ant BuildExcept ion has occured: exec returned: 2 -    > [Help 1]

[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the 
following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1]     http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

[ERROR]

[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-hdfs-httpfs
c:\hadoop>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Higher versions of Hadoop i.e. Hadoop-2.6, 2.7 or 2.8, then there is no need to build Hadoop-src for getting windows native Hadoop. Here is a GitHub link which has winutils for recent versions of Hadoop.

I have also faced the similar issue while building Hadoop-src using maven, these steps worked for me.

[Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) & Install Java in `c:/java/`

> (make sure the path is this way, if java is installed in program
>   files, then hadoop-env.cmd will not recognize java path )

[Download](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.8.2/hadoop-2.8.2.tar.gz) Hadoop binary distribution.

> (I am using binary distribution Hadoop-2.8.1)

Set Environment Variables:

```
JAVA_HOME = "c:/Java"
HADOOP_HOME="<your hadoop home>"
Path= "JAVA_HOME/bin"
Path = "HADOOP_HOME/bin"
```

> Hadoop will work on windows if [Hadoop-src](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.8.2/hadoop-2.8.2-src.tar.gz) is built using maven in
>   your windows machine. Building the [Hadoop-src](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.8.2/hadoop-2.8.2-src.tar.gz)(distribution) will
>   create a Hadoop binary distribution, which will work as windows native
>   version.

But if you don't want to do that, then download pre-builted `winutils of Hadoop distribution.`
Here is a [GitHub link](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils), which has winutils of some versions of Hadoop.

> (if the version you are using is not in the list, the follow the
>   conventional method for setting up Hadoop on windows - [link](https://dzone.com/articles/build-and-install-hadoop-on-windows-with-native-bi))

If you found your version, then copy paste all content of folder into path: /bin/

> Set all the .xml configuration files - [Link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/single_node_setup.html) & set JAVA_HOME path in hadoop-env.cmd file

From cmd go to:

```
<HADOOP_HOME>/bin/> hdfs namenode -format
<HADOOP_HOME>/sbin> start-all.cmd
```

Hope this helps.